# Saving a GIF File with no background

Tags: adobe-indesign, vector, gif

I have Corel Paintshop PhotoPro X3, and I bought a vector from Shutterstock that has multiple flourishes in it. I want to save each flourish as its own file. So I cut one and save it onto a new vector board, making it a GIF file. When I place it into InDesign, the image has a white background, but I need no background. I have researched this, and tried to follow steps from a YouTube video, but my software wouldn't cooperate. How do I save a GIF file that has a vector, and it has no background? If you can answer soon, that would be most helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome Katy!! I'm a bit confused. GIF files **can not** be vector. It is technically **not possible** to create a "vector gif". I'm sorry I don't understand your question based on that fact.

Comment: The file comes from Shutterstock as a vector. I am new to all this, so I am still learning terms. But it downloads as a vector file (eps), and then I cut and paste part of it, and save it as a GIF. Please help me to know if I am missing something. A friend thought InDesign was treating it as a raster, instead of a vector.

Comment: If you save it as a  gif it **is** raster. So, yes, InDesign will see any gif as a raster image. Whether or not that gif has a background color is completely dependent upon the original artwork and *how* you are saving it as a gif.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. When I open the file from Shutterstock, Corel says it's a raster layer. I see no background. When I cut and paste onto a new file, still no background. So do you know how it gets one in InDesign?

Comment: I'm not a Corel user. However, if you are using PhotoPro then you are ensuring it is a raster image regardless of what you purchased. The only way InDesign would *add* a background is if your image frame in InDesign had a color fill applied to it.

Comment: So it must be a Corel thing. So you gave me an idea! I placed the original file into InDesign, and no background! I will have to do that for each part of the vector I want to use, but this is a solution. So thank you. I will have to learn how to use Corel or Illustrator (when I get it) to do this.

Comment: The likely culprit is really *how* you were saving files with Corel. Just FYI, this is really software support and off-topic here. :) But glad I could help.